# Apply an operation on the value of column B depending on the value of column A - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
id  Wages   PayFreq
0   1013    Weekly
1   5000    Monthly
2   892     Weekly
3   2320    Bi-Weekly
4   1068    Weekly
```

I intend to perform the following operation:

```
if PayFreq == 'Monthly':
   (Wages / 4) * 52
elif PayFreq == 'Bi-Weekly':
   (Wages / 2) * 52
else:
    Wages * 52
```

I need to select the operation to apply to the wages column based on what is present in the PayFreq column. Any ideas ?

Comment: I see answer was reaacepted, for performane use apply here is worse solution, alhough seems cool. Rather not use it, becase slow, loopa under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sugest to use Dataframe's [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) as it is very simple and intuitive.

You can define a method you want to apply on the dataframe, you can choose either Lambda expression or explicit function for that. For example, here is a simple implementation with a function:

```
def func(row):
    if row['PayFreq'] == 'Monthly':
        return (row['Wages'] / 4) * 52
    elif row['PayFreq'] == 'Bi-Weekly':
        return (row['Wages'] / 2) * 52
    else:
        return row['Wages'] * 52
```

And in order to apply it on your dataframe (on the right axis):

```
df['NewWages'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

The result:

```
   Wages    PayFreq  NewWages
0   1013     Weekly   52676.0
1   5000    Monthly   65000.0
2    892     Weekly   46384.0
3   2320  Bi-Weekly   60320.0
4   1068     Weekly   55536.0
```

Comment: 'I would sugest to use Dataframe's apply as it is very simple and intuitive.'  Maybe you need to know simple not means better. here it is worse solution, because worse performance.Apply always use loops under the hood and if possible need avoid it in pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary, for not matched values use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) because map return `NaN` and multiple by `Wages` column:

```
d = {'Monthly': 52/4, 'Bi-Weekly': 52/2}
df['YearWages'] = df['PayFreq'].map(d).fillna(52).mul(df['Wages'])

print (df)
   id  Wages    PayFreq  YearWages
0   0   1013     Weekly    52676.0
1   1   5000    Monthly    65000.0
2   2    892     Weekly    46384.0
3   3   2320  Bi-Weekly    60320.0
4   4   1068     Weekly    55536.0
```

Solution with masks passed to [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['NewWages'] = np.select([df['PayFreq'] == 'Weekly',
                            df['PayFreq']== ' Monthly'], 
                            [(df['Wages'] / 2)*52, 
                             (df['Wages'] / 4) * 52], default=df['Wages']*52)
                            
print (df)
   id  Wages    PayFreq  NewWages
0   0   1013     Weekly   26338.0
1   1   5000    Monthly  260000.0
2   2    892     Weekly   23192.0
3   3   2320  Bi-Weekly  120640.0
4   4   1068     Weekly   27768.0
```

Comment: Forgot to mention.   As a new column ['YearWages']

Comment: The first way gets the correct results. Ex: ID 1 : 5000 a month should be 65000 a year.

Comment: @Yussuf Abdirizak, notice that the results here are wrong

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `np.where`, and adjust the conditions accordingly, **use the below just as an example not as a full answer**:

```
import numpy as np
df['NewWages'] = np.where(df['PayFreq'] == 'Weekly', (df['Wages'] / 2)*52,
                          np.where(df['PayFreq']== ' Monthly', (df['Wages'] / 4) * 52, df['Wages']*52))
```

which prints:

```
   id  Wages    PayFreq  NewWages
0   0   1013     Weekly   26338.0
1   1   5000    Monthly  260000.0
2   2    892     Weekly   23192.0
3   3   2320  Bi-Weekly  120640.0
4   4   1068     Weekly   27768.0
```

Comment: that's why i am saying you can use the code just update it to get the correct ones. It's an idea that I gave not an answer.